# Return null if date is not in date format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, ora-01858

I have couple of thousand rows query that was working fine for a long time and at some point started returning:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

I'm 99% sure it is date inserted with error.

My question here would be is there a function that would return a date or NULL if date is not in correct format?

Comment: Which Oracle database version do you use?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879283/filter-out-records-that-are-not-in-this-date-format-oracle. My answer has a function that checks if a date is in a certain format.

Answer (score 5):

`To_date` Can do exactly that for you since version 12.2. See the docs https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html

```
select to_date('not a date' default null on conversion error,'yyyymmdd') 
from dual;
```

Comment: I think it worth pointing up that while this will meet the OP's stated requirement, unless he utilizes this in project to actually identify and remediate the invalid data, it will remain invalid.  The very fact that he needs this feature is indicative of a flawed data design, wherein he is storing 'dates' as varchars.